.NET 6 Blazor Server entering login loop
I have a Blazor Server app that's written in .NET 6 that will sporadically enter a login loop and eventually fail to log the user in and send them to the Microsoft challenge page, but refuse to allow the user to manually login.  I'm not really sure what needs to be done to fix the issue as I have two other Blazor server apps running on the same server that don't encounter this issue.
appsettings.json
"AzureAd":{
  "Instance": https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  "Domain": "MyDomain.onmicrosoftonline.com",
  "TenantId": "MyTenant",
  "ClientId": "MyClientId",
  "ClientSecret": "MyClientSecret",
  "Scopes": "https://MyDomain.onmicrosoft.com/MyApi/access_as_user
},
"MicrosoftGraph":{
  "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1",
  "Scopes": "User.Read"
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAdd(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"))
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches()

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => 
{
  options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<StateContainer>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

I also have a StateContainer that hits the Graph SDK to pull back additional details about a user, like the photo, once the app has authenticated a user. This seems to be where the issue is occurring.  The StateContainer is injected into the MainLayout.razor page and GetGraphUser is called in OnAfterRenderAsync;
StateContainer.cs
private IConfiguration _config;
private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
private UserDto _user;

public StateContainer(IConfiguration config, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
  _config = config;
  _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task GetGraphUser()
{
  if(_user is null)
  {
    _user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().Select(user => new 
    {
      user.Id, user.EmployeeId, user.DisplayName, user.Mail
    });
  }
}

Has anyone else experienced this?  Can someone explain to me what I need to do to fix it?

Since this problem happens occasionally, it is difficult to reproduce. I noticed that the URL of the Instance is missing a /, it should be "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",.

I think this problem still needs to be solved by checking the asp.net core log. Maybe you can see the pattern through the logs, and this problem will recur under certain operations.

@JasonPan I'll give that a shot. I'll also see if I can find where that log is.  Thanks.
